# Modo Noturno html css js

Tags: javascript, html, css

Gente, eu encontrei uma API na internet de um switcher que muda o tema da página ao clicar no botão, porém eu não estou conseguindo fazer com que outras divs mudem de cor também, só o body que troca de cor, por favor me ajudem. eu tentei mudar o tema da div div teste1, mas sem sucesso, por favor, caso tentem ajudar, tentem fazer com que o tema permaneça ao dar refresh/recarregar a página, me ajudem por favor.

```js
function applyTheme (theme) {
    "use strict"
 document.getElementById("mypage").className = theme;
 localStorage.setItem ("theme", theme); 
}

function applyDayTheme () {
    "use strict"

 applyTheme("day");

}

function applyNightTheme() {
        "use strict"
 applyTheme("night");

}

function addButtonLestenrs () {
        "use strict"

document.getElementById("b1").addEventListener("click", applyDayTheme);
document.getElementById("b2").addEventListener("click", applyNightTheme);

}

function initiate(){
        "use strict"

 if(typeof(localStorage)===undefined)
  alert("the application can not be executed properly in this browser");
 else{
  if(localStorage.getItem("theme")===null)
   applyDayTheme();
  else
   applyTheme(localStorage.getItem("theme"));
  
 }
 addButtonLestenrs();
}

initiate();
```

```css
.day{
color:black;
background-color:rebeccapurple;

}
.night{
color:white;
background-color:black;
}

.teste1{
    background-color: blue;
    width: 250px;
    height: 80px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="Estilos.css">
 
</head>
<body id="mypage" >
 <h1>Choose a theme</h1>
 <button id="b1">Theme day</button>
 <button id="b2">Theme night</button>
 
 <p> This is an example of use of HTML5 storage API </p>

   <div class="teste1" >
    in
</div>
   
   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="change-theme.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O `localSorage` está funcionando corretamente, mas para alterar os estilos da `div .teste1`, você precisa criar uma classe para essa div baseada na classe de cada tema, por exemplo:

```
/* ESTILOS QUANDO A CLASSE DO BODY FOR .day */
.day .teste1{
    background-color: blue;
    width: 250px;
    height: 80px
}

/* ESTILOS QUANDO A CLASSE DO BODY FOR .night */
.night .teste1{
    background-color: red;
    width: 250px;
    height: 80px
}
```

Considerando que `.teste1` é filho direto do `body`.

Ou pode criar classes apenas com o que for diferente entre os temas:

```
.teste1{
    width: 250px;
    height: 80px
}

.day .teste1{
    background-color: blue;
}

.night .teste1{
    background-color: red;
}
```